# Highlighting strings in JavaFX TextArea

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Highlighting Strings in JavaFX TextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128535/highlighting-strings-in-javafx-textarea)

how to highlight the text in the textarea?
For example in ms-word if we write the text in the find option the same text will highlight in the text area in the same way i wanted to do that in javafx can any one help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately rich text is not yet supported (fx 2.2).

You can try next workarounds:

1. Use RichTextEditor
2. Use WebView
3. Draw several Text on Canvas
4. Just put Text/Labels with different formatting in HBox or TilePane.
5. Create a transparent pane over the TextArea and draw an opaque highlights, but this can be hard due to complexity of finding out exact words coordinates.

Comment: similar question was asked right before you, btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341672/make-portion-of-a-text-bold-in-a-javafx-label-or-text

Comment: Sergey Grinev:thanks for your answer.