# javafx - set the color for different words in text area

Tags: javafx-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Highlighting strings in JavaFX TextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346009/highlighting-strings-in-javafx-textarea)

```
TextArea text = new TextArea();
text.setText("select from");
```

now i want to set the different colors for those two words in the text area how to do that can any one help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rich Text Support in controls will be provided by JavaFX8 - http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23077.
Here is the CSS properties that are available for TextInputControl-http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#textinputcontrol

The possible workarounds are:-

1. Use a Rich Text Editor -
   http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/editor.htm
2. Put the text with different formatting in a HBox.
3. Draw them separately on the canvas.