# Text Formatted Differently in a single Table Cell

Tags: javafx

I would like to apply two or three different styles to text in a single cell in a TableView.

For example, I'd like the single cell to have text formatted like this:

**Edge of the Sun** [EP] *(Disc 2)*

I'd really like to do it with colors, as well.

I know how to apply styling to the entire cell, but I don't even know where to start for applying style to part of the text.

Putting the data in different columns isn't a viable option.

Comment: Put the logic in the `updateItem()` method of the table cell.

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/12341672/203657

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below's a quick example that

- uses [TextFlow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html) to style parts of a text
- implements a custom TableCell that has a TextFlow as its graphics and updates the text parts as appropriate

Note that there is a slight visual glitch: the prefHeight of the flow seems to return the accumulated height of the lines as if they were wrapped even if they aren't, thus making the row height oversized. As a quick hack, the computePrefHeight is overridden to force a single line - with the drawback that the other line/s simply disappear if the column width is decreased. Pretty sure there's something better but too lazy to further dig ;)

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * 
 */
public class TableFormattedCell extends Application {

    public static class MyCell extends TableCell<Locale, Locale> {

        private TextFlow flow;
        private Label displayName;
        private Label displayLanguage;
        public MyCell() {
            displayName = new Label();
            displayName.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
            displayLanguage = new Label();
            displayLanguage.setStyle("-fx-font-style: italic; -fx-text-fill: darkviolet");
            flow = new TextFlow(displayName, displayLanguage) {

                @Override
                protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
                    // quick hack to force into single line ... 
                    // there must be something better ..
                    return super.computePrefHeight(-1);
                }

            };
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            setGraphic(flow);
        }


        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Locale item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty || item == null) {
                displayName.setText("");
                displayLanguage.setText("");
            } else {
                displayName.setText(item.getDisplayName() + " ");
                displayLanguage.setText(item.getDisplayLanguage());
            }
        }

    }

    private Parent getContent() {
        TableView<Locale> table = new TableView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                Locale.getAvailableLocales()));
        TableColumn<Locale, String> countryCode = new TableColumn<>("CountryCode");
        countryCode.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("country"));
        TableColumn<Locale, String> language = new TableColumn<>("Language");
        language.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("language"));
        table.getColumns().addAll(countryCode, language);

        TableColumn<Locale, Locale> local = new TableColumn<>("Locale");
        local.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(c.getValue()));
        local.setCellFactory(e -> new MyCell());

        table.getColumns().addAll(local);

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane(table);
        return pane;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(getContent(), 800, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(TableFormattedCell.class.getName());
}
```