# How to address this warning? - Is a raw type. References to generic type should be parameterized

Tags: java

I have created a Custom Table Cell in JavaFX, [pursuant to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46880705/text-formatted-differently-in-a-single-table-cell), so I can have different font styling for different parts of the cell's text.

I use this Custom Table Cell on two different types of TableViews:`TableView<Track>` and `TableView<Album>`.

Both `Track` and `Album` implement the Interface `AlbumInfoSource`:

```
public interface AlbumInfoSource {
    public String getAlbumTitle();
    public String getFullAlbumTitle();
    public String getReleaseType();
    public String getDiscSubtitle();
    public Integer getDiscCount();
    public Integer getDiscNumber();

}
```

My Custom TableCell is typed with that AlbumInfoSource, so it can render cells for both a `TableView<Album>` and a `TableView<Track>`.

Here is the basic code:

```
public class FormattedAlbumCell<T, S> extends TableCell <AlbumInfoSource, String> {

    private TextFlow flow;
    private Label albumName, albumType, albumDisc;

    public FormattedAlbumCell () {
        /* Do constructor stuff */
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem ( String text, boolean empty ) {
        super.updateItem ( text, empty );
        /* Do pretty rendering stuff */
    }
}
```

And then I apply it to a column like this:

```
TableColumn<Album, String> albumColumn;
albumColumn = new TableColumn<Album, String>( "Album" );
albumColumn.setCellFactory( e -> new FormattedAlbumCell () );
```

**Which works perfectly fine**, but I get a warning on that last line, which says:

> Warning: FormattedAlbumCell is a raw type. References to generic type FormattedAlbumCell< T ,S > should be parameterized

If I change my FormattedAlbumCell class such that it extends `TableCell <Album, String>`, then the warning goes away. But then I can't use the FormattedAlbumCell for a `TableView<Track>`, I would have to duplicate the FormattedAlbumCell class make it extend TableCell, which seems dumb to me.

Is there a way to get these parameters straight without creating two separate classes?  It seems like the issue comes from the paramaterizing stuff having trouble with Interfaces.

Comment: Why do you have the `<T, S>` ?

Comment: Without it, I get an error rather than a warning on that line that sets the cell factory -- "Type mismatch: cannot convert from FormattedAlbumCell to TableCell<Album,String>".

Comment: Someone suggested in a now-deleted comment that I make it  "e -> new FormattedAlbumCell<> ()". This gives error "The type FormattedAlbumCell is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <>".

Comment: @JoshuaD but `FormattedAlbumCell` clearly *is* generic, if it has the declaration you have shown. Are you referring to the correct class?

Comment: I've edited the original post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `FormattedAlbumCell` has two generic type parameters (`<T, S>`) which, by the looks of things, are completely unused. Remove them.

```
class FormattedAlbumCell<T, S> extends TableCell<AlbumInfoSource, String>
```

becomes

```
class FormattedAlbumCell extends TableCell<AlbumInfoSource, String>
```

---

Your next problem is that [generics are invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po/). A `TableCell<AlbumInfoSource, String>` is not a `TableCell<Album, String>`, or vice-versa.

If you need to be able to create a `TableColumn<Album, String>` in your method then you need a `TableCell<Album...`, not a `TableCell<AlbumInfoSource...`. But you also want this to work for other implementations of `AlbumInfoSource`, so changing the cell won't work.

This means that you need to introduce another level of indirection via generics.

```
class FormattedAlbumCell<T extends AlbumInfoSource> extends TableCell<T, String>
```

This says that we can create different generic versions of `FormattedAlbumCell`, subject to the constraint that `T` is a more specific type of `AlbumInfoSource` (i.e. extends or implements it).

Now we can create a `FormattedAlbumCell<Track>` which would be a `TableCell<Track, String>`, or we can create a `FormattedAlbumCell<Album>` which will be a `TableCell<Album, String>`.

See also [Oracle's generics tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Comment: This causes an error on the line that is currently giving a warning -- "Type mismatch: cannot convert from FormattedAlbumCell to TableCell<Album,String>"

Comment: Album implements AlbumInfoSource.  FormattedAlbumCell is used by a handful of different TableViews, all of which display Classes which implement AlbumInfoSource.  The difficulty seems to be in sorting that out with parameters. Your comment about copy/paste isn't helpful.

Comment: Yea, that appears to be the thing that's causing the warning. Thank you.  Given that the code works and creating a duplicated class seems undesirable (see clarifying edits to my original post) what should I do? Just suppress the warning and move on? Refactor and accept duplicated code? Something else?

Comment: I can't change `albumColumn` -- then I'd also have to change `albumTable`, and in other places it expects a full `Album`, not just the narrow `AlbumInfoSource`.  If I change `FormattedAlbumCell` to `TableCell<Album, ...` I would have to make a duplicate version of that class that's `TableCell<Track, ...`, which seems undesirable.

Comment: Sweet! That did it. I also had to change `setCellFactory` as follow: `e -> new FormattedAlbumCell<>`.   Can you edit your answer to this solution and, if you're up for it, why this works?  Then I can accept it. Thank you!

Comment: @JoshuaD Sure, done. And yes, now that `FormattedAlbumCell` is generic you will need to use the generic type. In this case, the compiler can infer that you want an `Album` due to the type of the column, so the diamond operator is sufficient